# How to use vim keys in IDA 8.2 free?

Tags: macos, ida

I'm using the free version of IDA 8.2 on an ARM based masOS.
Is there any extension or key binding method that allows me to use the vi key in IDA?

I'm sure there's a related extension. I'm not seeing much when I search for it. Thank you.